# HTML/JSP/JS Rich Text Editor that saves to RTF file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, rtf, rich-text-editor

I have been looking for a while for an API/Tutorial/Program that is an entirely web-based Rich Text Editor.  I have found multiple, but I want a Rich Text Editor that has the following characteristics:

1. Browser-based, coded in HTML, JSP, Java Servlet, or Java Script.
2. Saves directly into an .rtf file
3. Can open .rtf files

Thank you in advanced, and sorry if this has been asked, as I have been searching for this for a while, but found nothing.

EDIT:
It might be worth noting;  This will be used at a school, as an alternative for Google Drive, so it only needs to support styling, no other "Special Effects".

Comment: Instead of RTF editor you might just try using an IDE...as it will be more comfortable for any kind of programming..

Comment: @Lakshmanan Do you have any examples of some?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question; I don't need a program that editors code, I already have one.  I want one, as I said, that is an entirely browser-based Document Writer, with styles an what not, that saves as an rtf.

Comment: ok i think you need a WYSIWYG editor..are u looking for somthin lik this..  [link](www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors">WYSIWYG editors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lakshmanan answer my question:
"ok i think you need a WYSIWYG editor..are u looking for somthin lik this.. [WYS‌​IWYG editors](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editor)